# json_decode and utf8 in php

Tags: php, json, utf-8

I have a big problem in php and that is when I use `json_encode` there are some `utf8` strings I include in the json array and after that it is being inserted in the database. After reading it from database and using `json_decode` I have a string like `"u062au0633u062a".`

Using `utf8_encode` or `decode` did nothing and also my page's encoding is `utf-8`! I will appreciate your helps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your JSON is likely to be broken, maybe already at the time of insertion into the database. You'll have to show some code.

Comment: Do you apply `stripslashes` or similar on the value?

Comment: @Pekka it is just json_encode and mysql_query! nothing more!

Comment: @Amir But somehow the `\‍` of the Unicode escape sequences `\uxxxx` seem to be missing.

Comment: If you don't than you have to find those little insects in your code that strips `\ ` before `u` in your json.

Comment: @Amir do not use so many '!'s, it reduces their impact

Comment: @hd1 ok sry. It's a bad habbit :)

Comment: as I said adding slashes did nothing. Please Tell me how can I manually encode it? Thanks

Comment: @Amir also, please show your code.

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php

ex:

```
$user->name = 'aaáá';
$user->email = 'emai@email.com';
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (infojson) values (".**addslashes(json_encode($user))**."'')");**
```

Comment: This answer need a better explanation. Post a link to the manual and some code isn't a good answer. Explain why you think this works.